# binding scope from html to the directive while doing ng-repeat and performing action which doesnt reflect back in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a required where i need to show the timer countdown for each and every person.
i wrote a directive which takes the doi(date of interview) from the html and perform some countdown operation in directive controller and update the timer every second.
Here is the html code :

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="candidateInfo in aCandidateDetails">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <a style="cursor:pointer">
      {{candidateInfo.name}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div stop-watch time="candidateInfo.doi"></div>
</div>
```

directive code:

```
angular.module('hrPortalApp')
.directive('stopWatch', function() {
        debugger;
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: false,
            scope: {
                time: "="
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                debugger;
                $scope.getTimeRemaining = function(endtime) {
                    debugger;
                    $scope.t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
                    $scope.seconds = Math.floor(($scope.t / 1000) % 60);
                    $scope.minutes = Math.floor(($scope.t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
                    $scope.hours = Math.floor(($scope.t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
                    $scope.days = Math.floor($scope.t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                    return {
                        'total': $scope.t,
                        'days': $scope.days,
                        'hours': $scope.hours,
                        'minutes': $scope.minutes,
                        'seconds': $scope.seconds
                    };
                }

                $scope.initializeClock = function(endtime) {
                    debugger;
                    $scope.clock = document.getElementById('clockdiv');
                    $scope.daysSpan = $scope.clock.querySelector('.days');
                    $scope.hoursSpan = $scope.clock.querySelector('.hours');
                    $scope.minutesSpan = $scope.clock.querySelector('.minutes');
                    $scope.secondsSpan = $scope.clock.querySelector('.seconds');

                    $scope.updateClock = function() {
                        debugger;
                        $scope.t = $scope.getTimeRemaining(endtime);

                        $scope.daysSpan.innerHTML = $scope.t.days;
                        $scope.hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + $scope.t.hours).slice(-2);
                        $scope.minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + $scope.t.minutes).slice(-2);
                        $scope.secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + $scope.t.seconds).slice(-2);

                        if ($scope.t.total <= 0) {
                            clearInterval($scope.timeinterval);
                        }
                    }

                    $scope.updateClock();
                    $scope.timeinterval = setInterval($scope.updateClock, 1000);
                }


                $scope.initializeClock($scope.time);
            },
            templateUrl: './views/stopWatchView.html'
        };

});
```

templete html code :

```
<div id="clockdiv">
<div class="tiles">
    <span class="days"></span>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
<div class="labels">
    <li>Days</li>
    <li>Hours</li>
    <li>Mins</li>
    <li>Secs</li>
</div>
```

problem what im facing here is every time it is updating the 1st ng-repeat row.
it is not showing anything for the other rows.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just a guess.. u using the same class/id to replace the innerhtml days/hours/mins/secs why not use ng-model instead. just doubt that it may be replacing first class/id found in html.

Comment: ng-model for what?@Neha

Comment: You setting  $scope.t.days/hour..etc value in innterhtml. rather keep it in $t. object and use same var and at html <span ng-model="t.days" > {{t.days}} </span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably caused by the line:

```
$scope.clock = document.getElementById('clockdiv');
```

An ID is expected to occur only once on a page. On each pass of ngRepeat, you start by requesting "the" `clockdiv` element, when you want "a" clockdiv element.

That said, a more angular-type approach would be to not update the `innerHTML` of your `span`s by hand, but instead bind to the scope parameters, like this:

```
<div class="tiles">
    <span class="days" ng-bind="t.days"><!-- this will bind to $scope.t.days --></span>
    <span class="hours" ng-bind="t.hours"><!-- this will bind to $scope.t.hours --></span>
    <span class="minutes" ng-bind="t.minutes"><!-- this will bind to $scope.t.minutes --></span>
    <span class="seconds" ng-bind="t.seconds"><!-- this will bind to $scope.t.seconds --></span>
</div>
```

And hey presto! Your clocks are automatically updated each time you update the scope variables, and you don't need references to elements in your code anymore. The line:

```
$scope.t = $scope.getTimeRemaining(endtime);
```

will be enough to update your page.